# Flutter assign Theme text style

Tags: flutter, text, themes, simplify

I was wondering is there is a better way to assign a certain default text style of my Theme to a Text widget than this approach.

```
Text(
 'Hello world',
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
),
```

I did assume there should be something like a separate Widget or a Text Method Text.headline1 or simply a style Command style: TextStyle.headline1.

But seems I have to go through the Theme.of(context) to get this.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Theme.of`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme/of.html) returns the [`ThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) value specified for the nearest `BuildContext` ancestor. If you don't use it, then you won't be able to access the theme configuration you may set and benefit from its advantages.

However, you can create a class called `Styles` where you can access the pre-defined colors, text styles and more:

```dart
class Styles {
  static const Color primaryColor = Colors.blue;

  static const TextStyle headline1 = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 20.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );

  static const TextStyle bodyText1 = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
  );
}
```

Here is an example of using it:

```dart
Text(
  'Hello world',
  style: Styles.headline1,
)
```

Comment: This would require defining an additional style for an already existing Parameter n the defined theme and therefore would create an additional maintenance effort if I would like to swap Themes.

Answer (score 8):

I think yon can't escape some boilerplate. For me this approach looks cleanest

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StyledText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  late final TextStyle? Function(BuildContext context)? getStyle;

  StyledText.headline1(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    getStyle = (context) {
      return Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1;
    };
  }

  StyledText.headline2(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key) {
    getStyle = (context) {
      return Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2;
    };
  }

  // ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text, style: getStyle?.call(context));
  }
}
```

And use the widget like this

```
 StyledText.headline1("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Theme.of(context)` is a great way to go for a variety of reasons, like switching between light and dark themes. I like to create a variable for the theme and text theme to keep things clean and efficient.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final theme = Theme.of(context);
  final textTheme = theme.textTheme;

  return Column(
    children: [
      Text('Heading Text', style: textTheme.headline1),
      Text('Caption Text', style: textTheme.caption),
      Text('Body text...', style: textTheme.bodyText1),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jared, i also considered the creation of a variable. Its however still the same approach involving the context and if not globally defined, would be still required in every class you might want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You define all Your Theme Style in Main like this

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      textTheme: TextTheme(
      headline1: TextStyle(
      color: const Color(0xFF232323),
      fontSize: 26.sp,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      fontFamily: "Mont Regular",
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Then use like this

```
 Text("A cloud-agnostic solution for Project and HR Management",
 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextStyle directly:

```
Text(
 'Hello world',
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0), // Etc...
),
```

Comment: Hi Boris, this does not reflect my intentions of maybe swapping themes. Bu thanks for your reply .